# ruby regular expression to see if only numbers

Tags: ruby, regex

I'd like to have a reqex that checks that every character is a number [0-9]+. I have tried:

```
'4th'=~/[\d]+/
'4th'=~/\d+/
```

but not working. How would I check for this?

thx

Comment: do you mean all characters are numbers?

Comment: yes, want to confirm that they are all numbers; 1 is ok but 1T is not

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
"12345" =~ /\A\d+\Z/
```

- \A = beginning of string (not line, string)
- \d+ = one or more digits
- \Z = end of string (not line, string)

Answer (score 10):

The simplest way is:

```
str !~ /\D/
```

Comment: And best readable feedback, I'd take `true/false` any day over `0/nil`